# Getting memory leak in fragments

Tags: android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have one activity , which has 3 fragments. Default fragment showing me below memory leak

i am searching and not able to figure out what could be the cause of memory leak.

Leaking: YES (Fragment#mFragmentManager is null and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)

Comment: You should provide the entire leaktrace if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: @LunaVulpo i am using commitAllowingStateLoss , and its working for me